# SQL syntax problem (multiple selects)

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I am having problems retrieving accurate data values with my stored proc query below:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE usp_InvoiceErrorLog
    @RecID int
AS

DECLARE @ErrorString as varchar(1000),
        @ErrorCode as int;

Select @ErrorCode = ErrorCode from tbl_AcctRecv_WebRpt Where RecID = @RecID;
IF NOT(@ErrorCode = NULL)
    Begin
        Select @ErrorString = ErrorDesc from tbl_ErrDesc Where ErrorCode = @ErrorCode
    End

Select  RecID, VendorNum, VendorName, InvNum, InvTotal, (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), InvDate, 106) AS [DD MON YYYY]) As InvDate,
        TicketRequestor, ErrorCode, @ErrorString as ErrorDesc
    from tbl_AcctRecv_WebRpt Where RecID =  @RecID
```

The ErrorDesc column (in the final select statement at the bottom) returns a NULL value, when it should return a valid string data.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you first query for that row and double check if ErrorDesc actually contains a value:

```
SELECT ErrorDesc WHERE RecID=@RecID
```

What does that return?  If NULL then there is no problem.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_InvoiceErrorLog  
@RecID int  
AS

DECLARE @ErrorString as varchar(1000)
DECLARE @ErrorCode as int

Select @ErrorCode = (SELECT ErrorCode from tbl_AcctRecv_WebRpt Where RecID = @RecID) 

IF (@ErrorCode IS NOT NULL) 
Begin 
    --its NOT NULL
    Select @ErrorString = (SELECT ErrorDesc from tbl_ErrDesc Where ErrorCode = @ErrorCode)
End
--optional it IS NULL
ELSE
    BEGIN
       SELECT @ErrorString = (SELECT 'It Doesnt Contain Anything!')
    END

Select 
     RecID, 
     VendorNum, 
     VendorName, 
     InvNum, 
     InvTotal, 
     (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), InvDate, 106) AS [DD MON YYYY]) As InvDate, 
     TicketRequestor, 
     ErrorCode, 
     @ErrorString as ErrorDesc 
FROM 
     tbl_AcctRecv_WebRpt 
Where 
     RecID = @RecID
END
```

This works for me.  Look at your if condition: **`IF NOT(@ErrorCode = NULL)` and look at mine `IF (@ErrorCode IS NOT NULL).`  You want to use IS NOT OR IS Rather then = when dealing with NULL**

Comment: If ErrorCode is not null, ErrorDesc should always return a value;
Why would you do SELECT ErrorDesc WHERE RecID=@RecID? You arent joining ErrorCode

Comment: @user279521, In my first example Im just telling you to do a lookup.  Please see my other code, it works fine for me.

Comment: @user279521 - Copy and paste my code into SSMS and run the query, then change your alias having a bunch of userXXXXXXX on stackoverflow :) is hard to manage.

Comment: having my alias as userXXXXXX keeps me anonymous :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
IF NOT(@ErrorCode = NULL) - ALWAYS false(NULL)!
```

It should be

```
IF (@ErrorCode IS NOT NULL)
```